# View in block doesn't sort by date whereas page does

Tags: views

I've got a 'archive' view in a block on my openblog drupal blog. In the view, the page view sorts ok, but in the block sorting by date doesn't work - it is always sorted by ASC.[image]

Comment: In your block view. Did you try clicking under SORT, Creationg Date and chaging it to Desc?

Comment: creation date doens't exist, only post date, date updated etc

Comment: oops yeah I meant post date, creation date is only for users.

Comment: yes I have tried that.

Comment: and SORT does not have any other field besides Post Date?

Comment: updated, revision etc. Like I said ordered by post date works for the page but not the block.

Comment: If you get [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com) I could take a look and help you.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, I'm at work.

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of your block view settings? You could use windows paint to save the image.

Comment: I've added a screenshot...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I needed to change the sort option inside the contextual filter.

Comment: Under CONTEXTUAL FILTERS -> content: created year + month there is a dialogue box with a sort option.